# how can I execute a string formatting with out using exec function in python

Tags: python, exec, python-3.6, standards-compliance

I have an exec statement to set the formatting of two variables in python 3.6. Even though the code works fine, I need to change this due to compliance issue. Please let me know how it can be done differently.

My statement: exec("{}='{}'".format(item,s))

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It is often a bad idea to assign variables this way and usually just storing them in a dictionary as key/value pairs is the right way to do it.  What is the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more:

```
locals()[item] = str(s)
```

will work for "simple" names (`foo`, `x`, etc.), but not for more complex assignments that your `exec` approach could handle (e.g. `instance.attr`)

In either case, "there must be a better way" to do what you're trying to do, but there's no context to help with that.

Comment: From `help(locals)`: "NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in  the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not
    covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees.",  Modifying locals is not recommended.